# Ruby file renaming and if syntax

Tags: ruby, file, if-statement, syntax, rename

I have two questions regarding the picture downloading program on pp. 108-109 from Chris Pine's book about Ruby. It's supposed to be a program that moves the photos from your camera (in my case it's D:/) to a designated folder, and renames the batch as you want. Here's the code from the book, without some of the comments. This code is part of Chapter 11, that it is so simple. At the end of the book the author has included a very detailed, and for me complex example of a program that does the same, so please don't take my post as a sign that the author doesn't have proper knowledge of Ruby.

```
Dir.chdir 'C:/Documents and Settings/Katy/PictureInbox'
# First we find all of the pictures to be moved.
pic_names = Dir['F:/**/*.{JPG,jpg}']
puts 'What would you like to call this batch?'
batch_name = gets.chomp
puts
print "Downloading #{pic_names.length} files: "
# This will be our counter. 
pic_number = 1
pic_names.each do |name|
    print '.' # This is our "progress bar".
    new_name = if pic_number < 10
        "batch_name0#{pic_number}.jpg"
    else
        "batch_name#{pic_number}.jpg"
    end
    File.rename name, new_name
    # Finally, we increment the counter.
    pic_number = pic_number + 1
end
puts # This is so we aren't on progress bar line.
puts 'Done, cutie!'
```

My first question is about the following passage:

```
new_name = if pic_number < 10
    "batch_name0#{pic_number}.jpg"
else
    "batch_name#{pic_number}.jpg"
end
```

The program didn't run for me, unless I changed it to the syntax I was familiar with:

```
if pic_number < 10
    new_name = "batch_name0#{pic_number}.jpg"
else
    new_name = "batch_name#{pic_number}.jpg"
end
```

Everything worked fine then. Although for some reason it changed the order of the photos.

My question is - is the syntax mentioned in the book wrong or the reason for it not working is different? This is also the first instance I see of similar syntax being used in the book.

Another problem I had was that I first named the batch "Sony", with a capital s, and the photos got deleted from the camera and were not moved to the folder (in my case it was C:/CameraPhotos).

When I tried to name the batch "sony", it worked properly. After that I tried adding to_s to the batch_name: "batch_name = gets.chomp.to_s", and it worked with the capital S. Does this have anything to do with the use of capital letters in Ruby, or the reason is different?

The final code of my program is, just in case:

```
Dir.chdir 'C:/CameraPhotos'
pic_names = Dir['D:/**/*.jpg']
puts 'What would you like to call hits batch?'
batch_name = gets.chomp.to_s
puts
print "Downloading #{pic_names.length} files: "
pic_number = 1

pic_names.each do |name|
    print '.'
    if pic_number < 10
        new_name =  "#{batch_name}0#{pic_number}.jpg"
    else
        new_name = "#{batch_name}#{pic_number}.jpg"
    end
    File.rename name, new_name
    pic_number = pic_number + 1
end
puts
puts 'Done!'
```

Edit: Upon further trying, the code that I had problems with worked. Excuse me for creating a confusing situation. I did really appreciate your answers and found them helpful, though.

Comment: Could you provide the exact error you got when trying to run the original code? (the error about the if block)

Comment: While you test I would advise you to change `File.rename` to `FileUtils.cp` so that you're not deleting the original file. (you'll need to add `require 'fileutils'` at the top of your ruby file)

Comment: Sokkyoku, actually the error I got was not related to the if block. I got the no implicit conversion of nil into String error regarding "new_name". That is why I thought the problem might be there. Then, if I remember correctly, I tried adding "to_s" to new_name in the File.rename line, I also tried adding the whole path to the folder, but then it gave me the permission denied error.
As a matter of fact, when I now try to run it as mentioned in the book, it works ok. There must have been another problem, but I don't know what it might have been. I'll mark the question as answered though.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. :) I actually tried also with FileUtils.cp and everything worked fine. I just wanted to do the program as it is given in the book.

As it seems that the program works with the syntax that I thought was problematic, please excuse me for taking your time with this question. I did encounter a problem, however, which seemed to have been resolved by changing the if syntax. Your answers were extremely helpful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1.

```
new_name = if pic_number < 10
             "batch_name0#{pic_number}.jpg"
           else
             "batch_name#{pic_number}.jpg"
           end
```

is a perfectly valid syntax, but this code might be (and, likely, should be) simplified to:

```
new_name = "batch_name#{'0' if pic_number < 10}#{pic_number}.jpg"
```

or, even better, to:

```
new_name = "batch_name#{pic_number.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}.jpg"
```

### 2.

Calling `to_s` on `gets.chomp` makes absolutely no sense and does absolutely nothing, since `gets.chomp` is already an instance of `String`.

I believe, the reason it failed with capital `S` is something related to OS, since you are on Windows and this OS is known to suck with the case of file names.

### 3.

The whole script looks like it was written by the person who has very limited knowledge of ruby and, therefore, I would use it on real photos with triple care.

Comment: "doesn't work because windows sucks" is amusing but not very constructive :)

Comment: @sokkyoku unfortunately, I have absolutely no clue about case sensitivity problems on Windows besides that I know they exist.

Comment: +1 for your opinion on the code quality. I cannot believe that Ruby code like that was published in a book.

Comment: While this is an interesting critique of the code, it doesn't answer all the questions (though this question is a bit of a mess, and close to "debug this for me")

Comment: @sokkyoku It does answer both questions, stated in the OP.

Comment: @mudasobwa actually it does, my bad. It answers the exact questions but doesn't explain really what's going on, which is a shame but your answer is proper.

Comment: Windows is case-insensitive but case-preserving, just like macOS.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The author of the book actually gives quite a detailed and complex example of another program for the same purpose in the appendix of the book. The one I gave above is just part of the specific lesson and uses stuff that has been introduced previously. That is why I believe the author seems to have a very good knowledge of Ruby. I'll edit my initial post.

Regarding the capital S, for some reason it did work properly with the "to_s", although it should have worked well without it.